# Cavity Input-Output Formalism: Physical significance and intuitive understanding

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, research-level, open-quantum-systems

I have spent a lot of time trying to understand the input-output formalism for cavities. I sort of understand the idea

1. Fields inside an optical cavity(our system) will have losses because the mirrors are not perfect.
2. Loss is taken into account by considering a bath(usually assumed to be a multimode field), to get coupled to the cavity's 'internal' field through these imperfect mirrors.
3. Due to this system-bath interaction, the mode operators of both the bath and the system gain additional time dependence. Their respective Heisenberg equation of motion form a pair of coupled linear differential equations that can be solved in the frequency domain by taking a Fourier transform of the differential equation.
4. If we are working with a single sided empty cavity the final relations between the internal(system) mode and the input mode is given as
   $$\begin{equation}
       a(\omega) = \frac{\sqrt{\gamma}}{\frac{\gamma}{2}-i(\omega-\omega_{0})}a_{IN}(\omega)
     \label{eqn: internal}
     \end{equation}$$
   and the relation between the input and output fields is given as
   $$\begin{equation}
       a_{OUT}(\omega) = \frac{\frac{\gamma}{2}+i(\omega-\omega_{0})}{\frac{\gamma}{2}-i(\omega-\omega_{0})}a_{IN}(\omega)
     \label{eqn: inout}
     \end{equation}$$
   Here, $a(\omega)$ is the system's field, in literature it is referred to as 'internal' mode and $a_{IN}(\omega)$ is the field of the **bath** at some initial time. I understand this as: the field of bath before the interaction took place and I understand $a_{OUT}$ as the field of the bath at a later time t i.e after the interaction.

Things I don't understand.

1. All resources I look at, emphasize that the first equation leads to a Lorentzian for the intensity transmission function. I see that it is indeed a Lorentzian but what does it mean in the context of relation between system and bath fields? Why is this important?
2. From the second equation, people conclude that there is frequency dependent phase shift between input and output. This one particularly confuses me. Both $a_{IN}$ and $a_{OUT}$ are ultimately bath fields. Why do we care about what happens to the bath? How is this important?
3. When we try to learn about the system why do we look at the expectation value of
   $\langle a_{OUT}^{\dagger}a_{OUT}\rangle$ ? I know that they are coupled and they are related to one another but this seems to suggest that my system(i.e the field inside the cavity) has a huge effect on the bath. The bath's field at a later time t has a big imprint of the cavity's internal field. From what I understand, typically when dealing with a bath, we assume that the system doesn't alter the bath significantly. Am I making a mistake in understanding this?

My references:

1. Chapter 7, Quantum Optics by DF Wall and G.J Milburn
2. M.J Collett and C. W. Gardiner, Physical Review A, Volume 30, Number 3, 1386, 1984
3. Chapter IV, Complement C-IV, Atom-Photon Interactions, Claude Cohen-Tannoudji et al

Any insight/intuitive understanding would be appreciated. Thanks.